# using data binder on service class, grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

In controllers it is possible to bind data from params to domain object easily.

e.g if Object A has b of B, then in your form you can put like this to create the r/ship:

```
<input type="text" name="b.id" value ="1"/>
```

But I want to do something in a service, unfortunately the binding only works on controllers.

so I found this searching:

manually import

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.DataBindingUtils;
```

and bind

```
DataBindingUtils.bindObjectToInstance(targetObject, sourceObject, null, null, null);
```

**but this is not working.**

On the target object I have a field "client.id", my expectation is a new client object with "client.id" will be created and r/ship will be setup (as in controllers) but getting this error:

```
Field error in object 'org.msad.agent' on field 'client': rejected value [null];
```

sourceobject => json map object

targetobject => domain object

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough information to know for sure why that didn't work, but you shouldn't be interacting with `DataBindingUtils` directly anyway.  A better idea is to interact with the data binder bean.  You can do something like this...

```
import org.grails.databinding.SimpleMapDataBindingSource

class DemoService {

    def grailsWebDataBinder

    def serviceMethodWhichDoesDataBinding(targetObject, Map props) {
        grailsWebDataBinder.bind targetObject, new SimpleMapDataBindingSource(props)

        // ...
    }
}
```

You haven't said what your `sourceObject` is and that may be relevant.

Comment: There is a similar question at http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-0-RC1-how-to-use-data-binding-correctly-in-this-scenario-td4648241.html

Comment: the import and inject service name are not equal? Alias?

Comment: the actual id of client is "SRH" so should I say  "client.id":"0001" or   "client.SRH":"0001"?

Comment: "the import and inject service name are not equal?" - I don't know what that means.

Comment: "the actual id of client is 'SRH' so should I say 'client.id':'0001' or 'client.SRH':'0001'?" - You want 'client.id':'SRH'.  How does '0001' relate to any o this?

Comment: 001 is the value, SRH is the id of Client. On target object I have Client ref with name "client". So how should I encode the json to mimic the r/ship?

Comment: I surrender.  Best of luck.